# Mangeto checkout email issue

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, onepage-checkout, validation

I have a problem with default checkout in Mangeto, customers can't register, even if they complete all fields in the checkout Billing section I have this error - **Invalid email address**. I try to install any other extensions like IWD and I have the same error.

I check with firebug: and in the Response I have this:

```
{"error":-1,"message":"Invalid email address \"\"."}
```

The error is look like in the following image:

[image]

Comment: Do you mind sharing the url?

Comment: Hi, please take a look: https://goo.gl/rKGsuo

Comment: Weird. Especially if there's no checkout extension in place. Might be a misconfigured firewall on your server - unlikely, but you can check for this by testing if the email is still available in index.php. Might be an observer messing with the request parameters: is there any custom code watching for the "company" field? This would be my first place to check. Apart from that, your best bet imo is to backtrace up to the point where the email parameter disappears.

Comment: I just add a fresh copy of magento files to the actual database and is the same error, so maybe something missing in the database?

Comment: You should do the backtrace approach. To make sure the issue is not caused by anything outside the scope of Magento, add something like `if ( strpos ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'checkout/onepage/saveBilling' ) !== false ) { file_put_contents ( 'var/log/email.log', sprintf ( 'File: %s Line: %d Value: %s%s', __FILE__, __LINE__, $_POST['billing']['email'], PHP_EOL ), FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX ); }` to the beginning of your `index.php`. You might want to add a condition so that logging will only take place if the request is yours. Check `email.log` if the email value is there. If this is the case ...

Comment: ... add the above line to different places of your code to see if the email value disappears somewhere. Start at `Mage_Checkout_OnepageController::saveBillingAction()` before line `$data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('billing', array());`. The address is probably missing there already so you'd have to got up the call stack.

Comment: Another approach is to hook into `Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http::setPost` and see if there's any unsetting of the email parameter. You might also consider searching your custom code for any direct modification of the $_POST variable.

Comment: A more advanced approach would be to add the logging code to an observer and listen to several events since simple backtracing won't get you anything happening in event listeners.

Comment: on the first code in index I see the value that I added in the email field in email.log, can you tell me again what I need to do for the second step?

Comment: Add the same logging line to `saveBillingAction` method in class `Mage_Checkout_OnepageController` and see if the email value is still there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48031/discussion-between-robertd-and-pong).

Comment: we can talk in chat? Anyway I put the code in onepage controller and I have the email there too, can you tell me please what I need to do here: Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http::setPost

Comment: I'm mostly busy for the next two hours, we can chat afterwards.

Comment: ok I wait you in the chat, just enter when you have time, thank you

Comment: Meanwhile, let's strike a new path to see where the error originates. Search for `Invalid email address "` (presuming this is not just a translation) in `*.ph*` files. There shouldn't be too many relevant hits. Check what's happening there by appropriate logging.

Comment: take a look here are all files that contain "Invalie email address":
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/IndexController.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Email/Address.php
app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php
app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sendfriend/Model/Sendfriend.php
app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/controllers/CustomerController.php

can you tell me what code I need to put in this files to check the email if is okay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turned out that the root cause of this was a corrupted DB. It missed customer's `email` attribute for the `checkout_register` `form_code` in `customer_form_attribute` table. This was fixed by issuing `INSERT INTO customer_form_attribute VALUES ('checkout_register', 9)` with `9` being the customer email attribute_id.

Comment: @RobertD you may have to add some more form_codes as well for other functionality in case those are missing, too. please see chat for further information.